# Is there any adb wait-for-device timeout method on Windows?

Tags: windows, subprocess, timeout, adb

I want to use time-limited `adb wait-for-device`, but it seems there's no time out function,

I workaround as below, is there any more efficient method to achieve it?

```py
#<python on Windows>
t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
cmd = 'date'
cmd = 'adb -s %s shell \"'+ cmd+ '\"'
r = 1
while(r!=0 and (t1-t0).seconds < 60):
    r = os.system(cmd)
    t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: doing a busy loop without sleeping like that is a bad idea because it'll consume 100% CPU. All multithread OSes have ways to do sleep-wait

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific Timeout method available but you can try

```py
def wait_for_device(self, timeout=5):
    """
    Perform `adb wait-for-device` command

    Args:
        timeout: time interval in seconds to wait for device

    Raises:
        DeviceConnectionError: if device is not available after timeout

    Returns:
        None

    """
    try:
        self.cmd("wait-for-device", timeout=timeout)
    except RuntimeError as e:
        raisefrom(DeviceConnectionError, "device not ready", e)
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell `Wait-*` cmdlets have timeout option that you can use. You can use [`Wait-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job) for this

```powershell
$timeout = 60
$job = sajb { adb wait-for-device }
if (-not ($job | wjb -T $timeout)) { spjb $job }
```

You can put it into the profile for reuse. In PowerShell run `notepad $PROFILE` and paste the below function

```powershell
Function Invoke-WithTimeOut {
    Param (
        [int]$timeout,
        [scriptblock]$script
    )

    $job = Start-Job $script
    $done = $job | Wait-Job -TimeOut $timeout
    if (-not $done) { Stop-Job $job }
}
```

For example to run with 40s timeout

```powershell
Invoke-WithTimeOut 40 { adb wait-for-device }
```

---

Another built-in solution is [ScriptRunner.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/scriptrunner.html) but it'll open the process in a new window

```powershell
ScriptRunner.exe -appvscript path\to\platform-tools\adb.exe wait-for-device -appvscriptrunnerparameters -wait -timeout=60
```

The behavior would be the same as when running the above PowerShell snippet with [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) and [`Wait-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process) instead of `Start-Job`/`Wait-Job`